# Nested div masked off by circular container div

Tags: css, html, background, mask, masking

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do this with CSS: I have a container div with a border-radius of 50% (circular). Inside of that is a rectangular div with a height of 30% positioned at the bottom of the container, and I want to be able to mask that off so that anything outside of the container's rounded border radius doesn't show. How do I accomplish this? Attached is a screenshot of what's currently happening, and this is my code:

```
<div id="coupon_container">
  <div id="meter_container">50c off</div>
</div>

#coupon_container {
    position: fixed; right:0; top:0; z-index: 100; color: #fff; width:170px; height: 120px; 
    #meter_container { 
        position: absolute; width: 110px; height:110px; .round; background: @greenDk; border:5px solid #fff; left: 60px; overflow: hidden; 
        .meter_level { width: 100%; height:30%; position: absolute; bottom:0; text-align: center; font-size: 1.6em; background: @limeLt; } 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In my experience, you can't get it to do this with straight css.  Things "spill out" of the border-radius.

Comment: Do you have more complete code you could post? I can't seem to recreate the problem, or even your screenshot, with what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like [the gradient solution that bookcasey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12964571/1397351) has posted. However, compatibility may be a drawback as IE9 doesn't support CSS gradients. So another solution would be this one:

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3915300)

The idea is to use a top padding of 70% instead of absolute positioning.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="coupon_container">
    <div id="meter_container">50c off</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#coupon_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 8em; height: 8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
}
#meter_container { 
    margin: 70% 0;
    height: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    background: lime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the effect you want using CSS3 gradients:

```
#coupon_container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 70, color-stop(100%, #fa8072), color-stop(100%, #ff0000));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa8072 70px, #ff0000 70px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa8072 70px, #ff0000 70px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fa8072 70px, #ff0000 70px);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fa8072 70px, #ff0000 70px);
  position: relative;
}

#meter_container {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/lauDK)

Comment: The demo is in Sass because Codepen supports Compass which makes CSS3 gradients much easier to work with, you could probably find a mixin that can patch up LESS.

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally missing something, but couldn't you just add "overflow: hidden;" to the round element, #coupon_container?

Comment: I'm not the OP, I just made a [simplified example](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/vufDL) on Codepen.